# Prove that $\int_{(k\pi)/n}^{(k+1)\pi/n}|\sin(nx)|\,dx=\frac{2}{n}.$

Tags: integration

$n\in\Bbb{N^*}$ and $k\in${$1..n-1$}

I have no idea where to begin. Get rid of the absolute value?

Comment: Hint: simplify the integral by letting $nx=u+k\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we start by getting rid of the absolute value. The important thing to note is that this is one "bump" of the graph of $\sin$; $\sin(nx)$ is either nonnegative on the whole interval $[k\pi/n,(k+1)\pi/n]$ or nonpositive on the whole interval, depending on whether $k$ is even or odd.

Once we do that, it's a very basic integral. Keep in mind that the endpoints will give us multiples of $\pi$ to evaluate the trig functions at, which means we can find them exactly.